# grep containing "-c"

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I want to search for `-c` using `grep`

For example:

```
$>ls -al | grep '-c'
```

But `grep` thinks it is an option.

```
$>Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
```

How can I search `-c` as a string?

Answer (score 6):

Tell grep where your options end:

```
grep -- -c
```

Comment: This one is recommended way, because this `--` method is available for most commands...

Answer (score 2):

You could either:

1. Escape the hyphen.

   ```
   grep '\-c'
   ```
2. Use the `-e` (`--regexp=`) flag

   ```
   grep -e -c
   grep --regexp=-c    # Not in POSIX, but supported at least in Linux and OS X.
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You use the `-e` option:

```
$ ls -a1 | grep -e -c
```

This is of course mentioned [in the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), thusly:

> -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
>
> Use PATTERN as the pattern. This can be used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-). (-e is specified by POSIX .)

Answer (score 0):

To stay on topic, the answer to your original question is to use either `--` to signal the end of options to process, or use `-e` to explicitly mark the option.

However, parsing the output of `ls` will produce an incorrect result if any of the file names contain a new line. Use `find` instead:

```
find . -depth 1 -name "-c"
```